# can't see variable set in callback?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

```
pushDocs: function (component, event, helper) {
        var pushFiles = component.get('c.pushFilesToEncompass');
        var percComplete = 0;
        var jobStatuses = null;
        pushFiles.setParams({ oppId: component.get('v.recordId') });
        pushFiles.setCallback(this, function (actionResult) {
            component.set("v.filePushJobIds", actionResult.getReturnValue());
            var lastCheck = 0;
            var firstCheck = 0;
            var timeout = 15;
            var elapsed = 0;
            var checkInterval = 2;
            while (percComplete != 100) {
                while ((new Date().getTime() / 1000) - lastCheck < checkInterval) {
                    //do nothing
                }
                var getJobStatuses = component.get('c.getJobStatuses');
                getJobStatuses.setParams({ jobMap: component.get('v.filePushJobIds') });
                getJobStatuses.setCallback(this, function (actionResult) {
                    jobStatuses = actionResult.getReturnValue();
                    var totalJobs = jobStatuses.length;
                    if (totalJobs == 0) {
                        percComplete = 100;
                    } else {
                        var completed = 0;
                        for (var i = 0; i < jobStatuses.length; i++) {
                            var jobStatus = jobStatuses[i];
                            if (jobStatus === 'Completed' || jobStatus === 'Aborted' || jobStatus === 'Failed') {
                                completed += 1;
                            }
                        }
                        percComplete = Math.round((completed * 100) / (totalJobs * 100));
                    }
                });
                $A.enqueueAction(getJobStatuses);
                lastCheck = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
                if (firstCheck == 0) {
                    firstCheck = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
                }
                elapsed = (new Date().getTime() / 1000) - firstCheck;
                if (elapsed > timeout) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            component.set('v.loaded', true);
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(pushFiles);
    }
```

I want to have a function which will wait on the client side until some server side jobs have been completed but i want a loop to basically give me back the status of these jobs and update a progress bar. The problem i am seeming to have is that my global variable "percComplete" does not update from the callback. I can see that my call back is executed multiple times in this loop, but the my function will always tiem out because the update to percComplete in the callback isn't visible to my loop. ANy ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
while ((new Date().getTime() / 1000) - lastCheck < checkInterval)
```

Do not do this. A [spin loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) will freeze the UI for the duration (up to a second in this case). Instead, use setInterval or setTimeout to check for progress if you'd like to check periodically.

Because you're using "real" functions, you're creating separate [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures); essentially, both functions see different versions of the same variable. Instead, consider using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which should allow each function to reference the same variable. Or, if you need IE 11 compatibility, get/set an attribute on the component:

```
while (component.get("v.percComplete") != 100) {
```

...

```
component.set("v.percComplete", 100); // etc...
```